# Finding the range of $\arg(1-z)$ when $|z|<1$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I came across the following statement while reading the proof of a fact involving the branch of logarithm:

> Since $|z|<1$ we get that $\arg(1 \pm z)$ lies between $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

I know that the (principal) argument $\arg(z)$ belongs to $(-\pi,\pi]$. However, unable to see how $|z|$ can affect the principal argument of $1-z$.

Also, when checking WolframAlpha for some properties of $\arg(1-z)$, I came across this:

[image]

Now I feel even more confused. Kindly let me know if you have any hints for solving this problem. I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious.

Comment: That part of WolframAlpha's output is assuming $z$ is a real number.  (the part that says "$z>1$" and "$z\leq 1$" should hint at this, since something like $z > 1$ doesn't mean much for complex $z$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z|=x^2+y^2<1$ describes an open disc of radius $1$ centered at $0$. Clearly,  $-1<x<1$, however  $|z+1|$ is an open disc translated in the real axis by $1$, in other words, $0<x<2$. Since $x$ is positive, then the argument of $1+z$ lies between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. For the other case add $\pi$, which will yield the same result

Comment: @rationalbeing yes, that’s a typo. The purpose was to show that $x$ is positive